# QuickTime RTSP/RTP over HTTP and Java

Tags: java, jmf, rtsp, rtp

I have a webcam. I can work with it using RTSP/RTP over HTTP tunneling (because only port 80 is opened for me).
QuickTime player plays video.

I want to catch this video and save it to disc in AVI container using java.
Can I use JMF? Does it support "RTSP/RTP over HTTP tunneling" ?

I heared about QTJ, but it is windows and mac os only.

My camera is linux-based, and I believe there is a Darwin inside

Comment: What do you mean by Darwin inside?

Answer (score 0):

(comment) 
JMF is dead. GStreamer is a living equivalent.
http://code.google.com/p/gstreamer-java/